# NewtonSoft Json Deserialization newtonsoft Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

If you are using NewtonSoft Json's JsonSerializerSettings to deserialize json string into an object and get the 'Additional text encountered after finished reading....'

1. Check if your Json content ends with a comma.
2. Additional parenthesis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the JsonSerializer's settings to ignore these additional content by setting the following to false.

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.CheckAdditionalContent = false;

Happy deserialization!

Comment: seems like `false` is the default value